# Able to connect to WAP, but cannot connect to internet.

Tags: wireless, networking

I have installed a new copy of Ubuntu 14.04. After installation, I am able to connect to the wireless network easily. And the wireless icon also shows connected. But, when I try to open any website, it doesn't open. And one more thing, it doesn't give error directly but continues to try to connect to the host. After some time, it fails to connect.

What steps do I need to take to troubleshoot/fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, there can be a problem with your WiFi.

For the second part, in which it "tries to connect and after a while fails," it is due to some glitch.

Maybe, and **just maybe**, your later problem can be solved in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/453289/internet-disconnects-by-itself-and-never-reconnects-unless-system-restarted).

Comment: Please run the script is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>